# Computing the norm of a vector expression ||aW+bX+cY||

Tags: haskell, ocaml

I am a PhD student. 
In the introduction of my thesis, I am insterested by the compromise between expressivity and performances of Linear Algebra tools.

As a simple example, I use the computation of the norm of a vector expression.
The C code for my example is:

```
float normExpression3(float a, float *W, float b, float *X, float c, float*Y){
double norm = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) // n in [3e6; 2e8]
{
    float tmp = a*W[i]+b*X[i]+c*Y[i];
    norm+=tmp*tmp;
}
return sqrtf(norm);
```

}

I compare the performances achieved with different techniques.
As the vectors are big (several million elements), the performances are limited by the memory bandwidth.
However, there are huge differences beetween the different approaches.

The optimized C version I wrote is not expressive (a new function has to be written to as a 4th vector) and very ugly (threaded and vectorized) but achieved 6.4 GFlops.
On the other hand, MATLAB code is very nice:

```
result = norm(a*W+b*X+c*Y)
```

but only achieves 0.28 GFlops.

C++ templates expressions *à la* Blitz++ provide both expressivity and performances to the user (6.5 GFlops).

As a part of my analysis, I would like to know how functionnal languages can compare to these approaches.
I thought about showing an example either in Haskell or in OCaml (AFAIK, both are reputed well suited for this kind of operation).

I know none of these languages. I could learn on of them to provide my example but this would'nt be a fair comparison: I am not sure to be able to provide an implementation allowing both expressivity and performances.

So my two questions are :
1) which language is best suited ?
2) how could the norm of vector expressions be computed efficiently without compromising the generality of the implementation ?

By advance, thank you !

Wilfried K.

---

Edit : corrected the type of the `norm` accumulator for `float` to `double`

Comment: You may have better luck in [Theoretical CS](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Did you benchmark Intel Array Building Blocks ? I think it is pretty unbeatable in term of expressiveness and efficiency.

Comment: This question would be considered (extremely) offtopic for the cstheory stack exchange.

Comment: @Alexandre : not testet ARBB for this operation. It is very efficient for this kind of operations but in my case is better introduced latter for comparison with my own library (kind of statically resolved ARBB targetting both CPU and CUDA GPUS).

Answer (score 5):

For what is worth, the following is an OCaml version of your function:

```
let normExpression3 a w b x c y =
    let n = Array.length w in
    if not (n = Array.length x && n = Array.length y)
        then invalid_arg "normExpression3";
    let (@) = (Array.unsafe_get : float array -> int -> float) in
    let rec accum a w b x c y n i norm =
        if i = n then sqrt norm else
        let t = a *. (w @ i) +. b *. (x @ i) +. c *. (y @ i) in
        accum a w b x c y n (i + 1) (norm +. t)
    in accum a w b x c y n 0 0.
```

It makes some allowances for performance, namely:

- Unchecked array access (or rather, array bounds checks manually hoisted out of the loop)
- Monomorphic array access
- Recursive inner loop to avoid boxing and unboxing the float accumulator
- Lambda-lifting of the inner loop to avoid referencing closed-over values

The last optimization should be checked against a closed-over inner loop, since with so many parameters register spilling might dominate over the cost of referencing closed-over parameters.

Note that one normally wouldn't bother with this kind of optimizations unless one were to compete in a benchark `;-)` Note also that you'll *need* to test this with a 64-bit OCaml, since arrays are otherwise limited to 4 mega elements.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this implementation. I'll post the result here.

Comment: I would added to the 64-bit recommandation that of using the native code compiler `ocamlopt`, instead of the bytecode generator `ocamlc` which cannot be expected to produce as fast a program. Another reason to use the 64-bit version of OCaml would be to guarantee `doubles` are aligned in memory. In the 32-bit runtime, they are spread over two cache lines 1 out of 16 times.

Comment: @Pascal: I tried this code compiled with camlopt 3.11.2. The code above achieves 0.73 GFlops (removing the lambda-lifting changes only around 1%). I tried to use the Bigarray module to force usage of single precision elements but the conversions are far too expensive (8 time slower).

So, Ocaml is 3 time faster than MATLAB, but far from C code (5 time slower than double precision C code).

Comment: @Wilfried, I'd expect the throughput to be 4x - 6x lower than a `float` C version. You mention a `double` test in C but in the question you report throughput for the `float` variant. Do you really have that low variance between data sizes?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) which language is best suited ?

Either are used for this kind of task. The primary concern would be availability of required libraries (e.g. for vectors or matrices), and whether there was any need for parallelism.

Libraries such as [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) and [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) in Haskell are well-suited. And in the case of repa, you get parallelism as well.

> 2) how could the norm of vector expressions be computed efficiently without compromising the generality of the implementation ?

One approach would be to use meta-programming techniques to generate specialized implementations of the computational kernels from high level descriptions. In functional languages this is a relatively common technique, based on small domain-specific languages, with custom code generators.

See e.g. [Specialising Simulator Generators for High-Performance Monte-Carlo Methods](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/polymer.pdf) or the work in OCaml on [FFTW.](http://www.fftw.org/)

Comment: Thank you.

I will try the repa package.
Do you know the performances of the vectorizer ?

Comment: Repa has been used for some high performance work, http://disciple-devel.blogspot.com/2011/03/real-time-edge-detection-in-haskell.html and vector as well. If you're new to functional programming, it may take some time to spin up your expertise, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much as a functional language answer per se, but please note that your implementation to calculate `norm` (in C) is way different how `matlab` actually calculates it.

And yes, there are indeed very good reasons for that. Most probably your approximation of `norm` is pretty much useless (as how it's implemented currently) for any real use case. Please don't underestimate the 'difficulties' related to calculating numerically superior approximations of `norm`s.

Comment: Our experience shows that this kind of implementation (with double accumulator) is precise enough.

If I first compute a vector Z=a*W+b*X+c*Y and then uses the norm function from different BLAS implementation, EXACTLY the same result is provided.

My measurements show that MATLAB do not fuse the loops to compute the expression and it does not seem to vectorize either.

Comment: FWIW, `matlab` and any other seriously to be taken linear algebra package relies on the accumulated experience and knowledge of (at least) past 5 decades. I'm sorry but I just can't buy that yours C implementation (as a general `norm` approximator) exceeds all of that. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have any doubt, and you shouldn't need to do an empirical assessment when you can look it up in the source code.

Comment: @eat: I think you raise a point. With Wilfried's data, there is no problem, but norm implementations are quite difficult to get right, due to overflow / underflow problems.

Comment: @nlucaroni: empirical assemments validate that roundness error do not corrupt the result.  

@eat,@Alexandre: exact, depending on datas, the norm algorithm may need to be specialized (eg: netlibs implementation). However, in many cases, this implementation is good enough.  

Concerning MATLAB performances : the time is not spent in the norm computation. the following implementation leads to the same performances:
`Z=a*W+b*X+c*Y;` `result=norm(Z)`

With Z preallocated, this implementation is as performant as previous one. Only 2.5% is spent in the norm computation (20% theoratically).

Comment: @Wilfried: I agree, only minimal part is spent on calculating the norm itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As don said, consider Repa.  Here is some simple code to get you started.

```
import Data.Array.Repa as R

len :: Int
len = 50000

main = do
    let ws = R.fromList (Z :. len) [0..len-1]
        xs = R.fromList (Z :. len) [10498..10498 + len - 1]
        ys = R.fromList (Z :. len) [8422..8422 + len - 1]
    print (multSum 52 73 81 ws xs ys)

multSum a b c ws xs ys = R.map (a*) ws +^ R.map (b*) xs +^ R.map (c*) ys
```

This still leaves you to find a good way to get the data from disk and into a Repa array.  I think reading it all in as a Llazy ByteString and using Repa.fromFunction should do, perhaps someone will chime in with a smarter way.

Comment: Or use something from the repa-io package, like http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa-io/2.0.0.3/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa-IO-Vector.html

Comment: Alright. sot the basic idea to get expressivity would be to generate the multSum function from an EDSL.
I'll first check the efficiency of Repa